# Scraping search result webpage

Tags: java, scraper

I'm trying to scrap the page where shows the result of some search. I've made a simple scraper and it's working, but when I try this searched page, the place where should be showing result of search, says "we cannot find the page you requested. Ask for help if you need". 
How can I scrap the searched web page so I the result of scrap would be different over time?

I've tried [this google search url.](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20web%20scraping%20search%20results) 
And [this is the one](http://www.work.go.kr/empInfo/empInfoSrch/list/dtlEmpSrchList.do?pageIndex=2&pageUnit=10&len=0&tot=0&relYn=N&totalEmpCount=0&jobsCount=0&mainSubYn=N&region=41000&lastIndex=1&siteClcd=all&firstIndex=1&pageSize=10&recordCountPerPage=10&rowNo=0&softMatchingPossibleYn=N&benefitSrchAndOr=O&keyword=CAD&charSet=EUC-KR&startPos=0&collectionName=tb_workinfo&softMatchingMinRate=%2066&softMatchingMaxRate=100&empTpGbcd=1&onlyTitleSrchYn=N&onlyContentSrchYn=N&serialversionuid=3990642507954558837&resultCnt=10&sortOrderBy=DESC&sortField=DATE) I'm actually trying to scrap.
This is the code for scraping.

```
    try
    {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT);
        Document htmlDocument = connection.get();
        this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
        String qqq=htmlDocument.toString();
        System.out.println(qqq);
        if(connection.response().statusCode() == 200) // 200 is the HTTP OK status code
                                                      // indicating that everything is great.
        {
            System.out.println("\n**Visiting** Received web page at " + url);
        }
        if(!connection.response().contentType().contains("text/html"))
        {
            System.out.println("**Failure** Retrieved something other than HTML");
            return false;
        }

        Elements linksOnPage = htmlDocument.select("a[href]");
        System.out.println("Found (" + linksOnPage.size() + ") links");
        for(Element link : linksOnPage)
        {
            this.links.add(link.absUrl("href"));
            System.out.println(link.absUrl("href"));
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        // We were not successful in our HTTP request
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code, an example input, and the actual error. Your question is too vague...

Comment: I edited the webpage and my code. thanks!